# Using google fit api from a backend server

Tags: android, google-api, backend, google-oauth, google-fit

I'm writing an android application which needs to read user's fitness data (steps, calories, etc) from a back end server. this server will read the data and push notifications to android app if necessary.

I managed to get the authentication part done and app is now sending the code recevied from oauth flow to the backend server (followed [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access) example) and the server successfully exchanges the code access and refresh tokens.

The problem is I did not find any resource on how to access the fitness data from a backend server in the google samples. I found the library

`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-fitness</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev16-1.21.0</version>
</dependency>`

but did not find any guideline on how to use this in a backend server. Is there any guideline on how to access the fitness data from a backend server without user interaction?

Thanks in advance and I searched stackoverflow and internet with no success

Comment: That is the Android API stuff.  To access from a back end server you will need to use the Rest API's  There is documentation at https://developers.google.com/fit/  You should be aware that the Google servers and the Android device are synced irregularly so data on the device may not be visible for hours or even days.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As I understood the library I mentioned is a wrapper around the rest api. the problem is there are examples for some other libraries like, drive, profile, etc. but I was not able to find some guide about this particular library usage. any help?

Comment: no.  My usage of the rest API has been direct, I have to deal with a load of different back ends so have all the messy stuff around already. I am actually working on Android but going to the rest API's rather than the Android API's as that fits in far better with my flow where I just upload data once the user has finished there activity.

Comment: Thanks. and one more thing I might have a near real time requirement for the data. in that case would you suggest to use the android api and sync the data via that?

Comment: Yes for realtime if the user is going to be looking on there device then only a query on the device will match what they see in say the FIT app.  Synchronise is every hours or so with wifi and slower still with just mobile data.  Regular complaints about it in the G+ Fit developers group which is a good source of information.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look in to the option of collecting the data on android side instead of backend side.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs this, there is javadoc available [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/fitness/v1/java/latest/). And here is a simple example of a batch request for the user's height and weight from the backend server:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(activeUser.getAccessToken());

Fitness fitness = new Fitness.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), 
                                      JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), 
                                      credential)
        .setApplicationName("MyApp")
        .build();

BatchRequest batchRequest = new BatchRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), credential);
fitness.users()
        .dataSources()
        .datasets()
        .get("me", "derived:com.google.weight:com.google.android.gms:merge_weight",
                        String.format("0-%d", System.nanoTime()))
        .queue(batchRequest, new WeightRequestCallback(activeUser));

fitness.users()
        .dataSources()
        .datasets()
        .get("me", "derived:com.google.height:com.google.android.gms:merge_height",
                String.format("0-%d", System.nanoTime()))
        .queue(batchRequest, new HeightRequestCallback(activeUser));


batchRequest.execute();
```

`HeightRequestCallback` and `WeightRequestCallback` extend `JsonBatchCallback<Dataset>`

Comment: As per the discussion above I switched to android app for the development. up voted the answer and if someone confirmed that this works or If I happen to run to this will accept the answer