# when I insert data in to Google fit the inserted data is not showing immediately in Google fit app

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I have followed  https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history to insert the data in to the google fit from my App. The data has been inserting successful, but I couldn't able to see data immediately in google fit. It is taking more than 10 to 15mins to show in google fit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I guess this is the expected behavior. It is also stated that *"The result may not be immediately available"*. You can see in this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-wear/il0Vh-CDv8Q). You may also check this [SO related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173213/). You should be aware that the Google servers and the Android device are [synced irregularly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740630/using-google-fit-api-from-a-backend-server#comment59182619_35740630) so data on the device may not be visible for hours or even days.

Comment: Is there any way to directly insert in to google fit app so that the result may  be immediately effect.

Comment: in my case in not show at all even after hours, onSucess and onComplete is called